# Combine lines 1-8, 9-16, etc. in a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, fopen

I have a large text file that looks like this:

```
line1: Date

line2: data

line3: data

line4: data

line5: data

line6: data

line7: data

line8: (blank)

line9: Date (repeats itself from here)
```

I need to read this txt file and merge lines1-8 onto a single line, save this line as a variable, then move on to lines9-16, merge onto a single line, save this line as a variable, etc. Any idea how to code this?
Alternatively if there's a way to remove every '\n' except for every 8th '\n' that might even be easier, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thank you! All answers are fantastic solutions. Much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Look at `grouper` in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the docs:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Now you can loop over every group of 8 lines:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for group in grouper(f, 8):
```

If you want to join each group together into a single string that you can write to a new file:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for i, group in enumerate(grouper(f, 8)):
        with open(f'out_{i}.txt', 'w') as outf:
            outf.write(''.join(group))
```

If you want to turn all the internal newlines into spaces:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for i, group in enumerate(grouper(f, 8)):
        with open(f'out_{i}.txt', 'w') as outf:
            outf.write(''.join(group).replace('\n', ' ') + '\n')
```

The nice thing about doing things generator-style is that you can change your grouping rule without changing the rest of the code. For example, if you want to split on every line that matches a date format, as in [Miguel Ortiz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338693/908494):

```
from itertools import groupby

rdate = re.compile(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)')
with open(path) as f:
    for i, (k, group) in enumerate(groupby(f, rdate.search)):
        with open(f'out_{i}.txt', 'w') as outf:
            outf.write(''.join(group).replace('\n', ' ') + '\n')
```

Comment: I like your answer and how simple it's for a fixed input.

Answer (score 2):

Split by "\n" then make a list of chunks of 8 lines of data joined via "," (or whatever delimiter you want):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = f.read().split('\n')
output = [','.join(l[j*8:j*8+8]) for j in range(int(len(l)/8))]
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the answers, but I add mine which has more control about the content of the file and could be used in the future if the amount of lines in the input file varies, *(of course you can add more control to cover more corner cases)*.

This one will look for a line with date format, then associate the data to that date:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# parse zemone's data

import re
fileName="zemone.txt"
data={}

with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f :
        if re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',line) :
            myIndex=line.strip('\n')
            data[myIndex]=''
        elif line == '\n' :
            pass
        else :
            data[myIndex] += ' ' + line.strip('\n')

for x in data :
    print x, data[x]
```

> **Output:**

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/projects/python/data_manipulation$ python parse_zemone.py 
01/01/2018  data1 data2 data3 data4 data5 data6
01/02/2018  ndata1 ndata2 ndata3 ndata4 ndata5 ndata6
```

> **txt file**

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/projects/python/data_manipulation$ cat zemone.txt 
01/01/2018

data1

data2

data3

data4

data5

data6



01/02/2018

ndata1

ndata2

ndata3

ndata4

ndata5

ndata6
```

Comment: Try out `for group in itertools.groupby(f, re.compile(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)').search):`

Comment: Thanks abarnert! I'll look it tomorrow.